# Azure Search support to index on Image /Binary data types in SQL Server, is it possible? or there any alternative possibilities?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We came with a requirement to Search SQL table which contain documents data in Image/binary column type. we are trying to do this with Elastic-search and Azure Search. we can able to proceed with Elastic-search but hit roadblock on Azure Search as indexing is not possible for these data types thru indexer.

can any body help us, is there any possibilities to achieve this with Azure Search?

Comment: A workaround is to extract the document text upon insert/update, store the text on another column, then index that column instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my [response to your question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ec7c4a32-a794-436e-a96c-58a31af8b994/azure-search-support-to-index-on-image-binary-data-types-in-sql-server-is-it-possible-or-there?forum=azuresearch).

In short, currently, in order to use Azure Search built-in document extraction capabilities, the files need to be stored in Azure blob storage. Then, you can use the [blob indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage).

Comment: Thanks for the update. we are taking alternative apporach by converting the image data type to string while loading data to Azure Search for indexing.